# Parsing sheets of Excel file with Talend

Tags: excel, talend

I'm working on Talend and recently my goal was to parse each sheet of an Excel file to do some different things.

For example,  nowadays I'm working on an excel file composed of 4 sheets and I want to replace some values by other values in both sheets. The output file would be the same excel file, composed of its 4 sheets with all the values, including those replaced.

I used tFileExcelWorkbook and tFileExcelSheetList to parse my Excel file, then tFlowIterate to create a global variable (name of sheet) and tReplace to make the search/replace.
But actually I'm stuck.. I really don't know How to make it to create the same excel file, with the same sheets by using that tReplace component.

Do you know what I could do to solve that problem, **and more generally how to do to parse sheets of an Excel file** ?

Thanks !
Julien

Comment: Is the schema of each of the four worksheets the same? Which columns of which sheets have values which would potentially be replaced ? Please provide a sample schema and definite scenario

Answer (score 0):

Julien,

Easier way to parse/process sheets in an Excel would be to use a tFileInputExcel and in the "Sheet list" define the sheet names/position that needs to be worked on.

- Renju MAthews